# Getting a meaning of the string

Tags: ruby, string, encoding

I have the following string `"\u3048\u3075\u3057\u3093"`. I got the string
from a web page as part of returned data in JSONP.

What is that? It looks like UTF8, but then should it look like `"U+3048U+3075U+3057U+3093"`?

What's the meaning of the backslashes (`\`)?

How can I convert it to a human-readable form?

I'm looking to a solution with Ruby, but any explanation of what's going on here is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is Unicode, but not in UTF-8, it is in UTF-16.  You might ignore surrogate pairs and deem it as 4-digit hexadecimal code points of a Unicode code character.

Using Ruby 1.9:

```
require 'json'

puts JSON.parse("[\"\\u4e00\",\"\\u4e8c\"]")
```

Prints:

```
一
二
```

Answer (score 4):

The `U+3048` syntax is normally used to represent the Unicode code point of a character. Such code point is fixed and does not depend on the encoding (UTF-8, UTF-32...).

A JSON string is composed of Unicode characters except double quote, backslash and those in the U+0000 to U+001F range (control characters). Characters can be represented with a escape sequence starting with `\u` and followed by 4 hexadecimal digits that represent the Unicode code point of the character. This is the JavaScript syntax (JSON is a subset of it). In JavaScript, the backslash is used as escape char.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode characters in JSON are escaped as backslash u followed by four hex digits. See the string production on [json.org](http://www.json.org/).

Any JSON parser will convert it to the correct representation for your platform (if it doesn't, then by definition it is not a JSON parser)